# Editing Source Code in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

The company I am working with hosts their webpage on Wordpress. They want me to edit some of the code in order to do various things, such as enable a photo container to be a moving slideshow.

Figuring out the javascript and html to achieve the results they desire is not problematic for me. However, I am unsure how to get full access to the Source Code of the site. I have privileged access to the backend of the site but in wordpress when you go to edit it only shows some of the basic html tags while hiding the `<div>` and `<script>` tags and code.  Is there any way edit the page in its source code format? I don't want to have to go through the simplified and less expressive/less control Wordpress interface, and I don't even know if   I can achieve the desired results with it.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is in the "theme".. /wp-content/themes/my-theme-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wordpress, there are two main parts to the website's front and backend: the core WP files and the theme that is used. (And other important aspect to a WP site is the database, where all content is stored, including text/images entered in the admin backend.)

Core WP files are not to be changed because they get overwritten with each update. What you want to work with is the theme. Look in Appearance>>Themes and see what the active theme is for the site. It will also tell you the name of the folder the theme files are in.

With FTP, go to root/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name. That's the php, html and css source of the displayed part of the site. Uploaded images are in /uploads/, and plugins in /plugins/.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development to get an idea of how themes are built and how to modify them.

See the rest of the docs at WP to see how to work with plugins, add other javascript correctly so it doesn't conflict with WP's included javascripts, etc. All the docs you really need are at wordpress.org

Comment: Ah. Ok, looks like this will be a little more complicated then I hoped. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you try and edit individual pages you're approaching the problem in the wrong way. You probably want to be using a plugin or modifying a plug-in to create the slideshow you need. There are many plugins for wordpress that do what you seem to need.

[slider-widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pictures-from-folder-slideshow/) is one such pluging

Comment: Ok, thank you, but does that mean there is no way to be allowed to free form edit all the source code of a page?

Comment: Well depends on what you define to be a page. If you mean the generic template used for a page, then yes you can go about changing those, it's called the theme, and by editing the theme files you can change the template that is used to generate actual pages. If you're referring to individual posts, you can change the html of that post by clicking the HTML tab when editing a post. I'm unsure of whether the set up will strip any javascript entered into your posts, but it's quite possible. Like I said, the best way to implement this would be to use a plugin, or alternatively edit the theme.